# Caching LESS Bootstrap with Grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs, bower

I'm using grunt to manage my front end web app, and wondering if there's any way of speeding up its precompile process. It takes around 2sec to compile the LESS file (including bootstrap), and to me it would make sense if the bootstrap.less didn't need to be recompiled each time.  Maybe it is already cached by default, but is there any way of speeding the build up?

Gruntfile sample:

```
grunt.initConfig({
watch: {
    haml: {
        files: '*.haml',
        tasks: ['haml'],
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        },
    },
    js: {
        files: ['*.js'],
        tasks: [],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        }
  },
  css: {
        files: ['*.css'],
        tasks: [],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        }
  },
  less: {
        files: ['style.less'],
        tasks: ['less'],
  },


},
```

Comment: Does `style.less` imports `boostrap.less`? If so then I'm afraid no caching is possible since the `style.less` can redefine/override variables and mixins used by `boostrap.less` and the cache becomes invalid even if Bootstrap files are not modified at all (and neither compiler nor grunt tasks can know if when or if such invalidation actually occures). If `style.less` and `boostrap.less` are compiled to independent css files then simply assigning them to a different `watch` subtasks would do the trick.

Comment: Yes it does.  Thanks for the explanation!  I guess 2 seconds isn't too bad a price to pay

Answer (score 1):

You got to check out `grunt-newer` to configure Grunt tasks to run only when files have changed.

See https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer